# Using client-testimonials-carousel plugin, having the arrows not move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this plugin and it works perfectly:

https://codyhouse.co/demo/client-testimonials-carousel/index.html

however I'm not too sure how to get the arrows to stay put and never move. Right now they center themselves based on the height of the div and I just want them to stay where they are instead. If someone could show me what they changed so I can also learn that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this css:

```
.flex-direction-nav li a::before, .flex-direction-nav li a::after {
    background-color: white;
    content: "";
    height: 13px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    width: 2px;
}
```

Change the `top: 50%;` to whatever you want. Like `top: 200px` for example.

The `top: 50%` will get the height of the parent element and move the own element `50%` down. This can be disabled by adding a fixed declaration.

If you cant edit the css from your plugin, include your own css-file and paste this into it:

```
.flex-direction-nav li a::before, .flex-direction-nav li a::after {
    top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider sticking with the moving arrows. Reason for suggesting this is that your choice of fixed top position is unlikely to be as pleasing as the centred version. Say you choose

```
top: 100px;
```

It will look great for a testimonial that generates a 220px high block because the 100px point is roughly central.  But it will look ugly when the testimonial block is 130px high and the arrow is close to the bottom of the block.

Your sample testimonials have either 3 or 4 lines only. Try it with single-line testimonial and a 7 line version and see how you feel about fixing the position.

Its a nice looking site so far - good work.